# Input Tag Helper Alignment when Alert Displays

Tags: tag-helpers

Here is my cshtml. My input tag helpers line up correctly, but upon validation they move. I've tried left aligning my alert but that did not work.

```
<div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-10">                    
                      <label style="display: inline-block; width: 150px; text-align: right">Last Name:</label>
                         <input asp-for="NewUser.LastName"/>
                         <label class="alert-danger">@ViewData["LastNameErrorMessage"]</label>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

[image][image]

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.